# i cannot be resolved to a variable.i am writing a java program which reverses a string as argument

Tags: java, syntax

```
package String;

public class A {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(reverse("java"));
    System.out.println(reverse("yuvaraj"));
    }
    public static String reverse(String s)
    {
    int len=s.length();
    String s1=" ";

    for(int i=len-1;i>=0;--i);
    {
        s1+=s.charAt(i);//in this line problem occurs
    }
    return s1;
    }
}
```

i am getting a problem in "i" of charAt(i)

Comment: remove `;` from the `for` loop

Comment: i declared i outside and it compiled but error showing in console

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1
 at java.lang.String.charAt(Unknown Source)
 at String.A.reverse(A.java:17)
 at String.A.main(A.java:7)

Comment: Change `for(int i=len-1;i>=0;--i);` to `for(int i=len-1;i>=0;--i)`.

Comment: thank u rustam it worked

Answer (score 1):

Remove the semicolon after the loop

```
for(int i=len-1;i>=0;--i);   // is causing the issue
```

The semicolon after the loop causing the loop body to ends there without doing anything like  `for(int i=len-1;i>=0;--i){}` no body and because of this the line `s1+=s.charAt(i);` is not in loop body causing the error you got. So change it to

```
for(int i=len-1;i>=0;--i)
```

[**DEMO**](http://ideone.com/bDABv8)

Answer (score 0):

Remove semicolon in the end of the line in

```
for(int i=len-1;i>=0;--i);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static String reverse(String s)
    {
    int len=s.length();
    String s1="";
    for( int i=len-1;i>=0;i--)
    {
        s1=s1+s.charAt(i);

    }
    return s1;
```

Comment: You should never use String concatenation in a loop. Use a `StringBuilder` instead.