# Why is a variable not recognized after ";" in java

Tags: java

This piece of code works

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
//print from 1-100

    for (int i = 0;
         i < 100;
         i ++) 
    {
    System.out.print(i + "\n ");
    }
}
```

But this one does not.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
//print from 1-100
    for (int i = 0;
         i < 100;
         i ++);     // Why does ; stop i from being recognized?
    {
    System.out.print(i + "\n ");
    }
}
```

Why does putting a `;` after `i++)` stop the variable from being recognized  in `System.out.print(i + "\n ");`?

Is this unique to Java?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [i cannot be resolved to a variable.i am writing a java program which reverses a string as argument](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32665527/3841803)

Comment: putting a semi-colon after your for loop means that you dont have a body afterwards.  That means `i` is not defined in the scope anymore.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [i cannot be resolved to a variable.i am writing a java program which reverses a string as argument](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32665469/i-cannot-be-resolved-to-a-variable-i-am-writing-a-java-program-which-reverses-a)

Comment: Thanks I got it.  However I still do not understand the full  scope of the semicolon.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The extra `;` at the end means that the for loop becomes like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    //Empty
}
```

Thus, in this piece of code:

```
{
System.out.print(i + "\n ");
}
```

`i` is out of scope and cannot be recognized, since your code will essentially look like so:

```
for (int i = 0;
     i < 100;
     i ++)     // Why does ; stop i from being recognized?
{/*FOR LOOP*/}
{
System.out.print(i + "\n ");  //i is out of scope here.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No a for-loop is defined in java and quite a lot of other languages as:

```
BasicForStatement:
for ( ForInitializer? ; ForConditionExpression? ; ForPostExpression? ) Statement
```

This statement can either be a block, like this:

```
for(...){
    ...
}
```

Or a standalone statement. A lone `;` is interpreted as a no-op statement. Thus:

```
for (int i = 0;
     i < 100;
     i ++); // <-- statement that executes in the for-loop
{ // <-- this block doesn't belong to the for-loop
System.out.print(i + "\n");
}
```

Since the code in the block then doesn't belong to the loop, `i` isn't in scope.

Comment: You said expression but you probably meant statement - they aren't the same thing.

Comment: @skeggse sry, i sometimes confuse them

Comment: No worries, my comment was brief but not intended to be terse.

Comment: @skeggse thanks for mentioning it, i didn't even notice

Answer (score 0):

Your loop is the equivalent of

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i ++)
        ;
```

You can avoid curly braces in a for loop (but is bad practice) if you have only one statement to execute into the loop.

If you add curly braces, you got:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i ++) {
    ;
    System.out.print(i + "\n ");
}
```

As you can see you have a single `;` that's the equivalent of a nop instruction. But is into the loop, so everything between curly braces will be executed.

A little hint for you: format in a better way your code to see what's  happening in a clear way.